# How can I avoid showing unused legend entries in vega-lite?

Tags: legend, vega-lite

I have multiple plots (pie charts, scatterplots, barcharts) in a dashboard, all of them are colored by a third attribute. Therefore I created a custom color scale to use in every plot.
Now, the whole scale is shown in every legend in every plot, even if only 3 of the colors are in fact necessary, as there are no data points for the other colors.
How can I make vega-lite showing only those legend entries with existing data.
I need a global solution, as I have different data sets to which I want to apply the same code of course. Thanks in advance for your answers!

[image: Unused legend entries]

```
   EEKData = {
        "values": [
        {EEK: "A+", Energieträger: "Wärmepumpe", "frequency": 1},
        {EEK: "A", Energieträger: "Gas", "frequency": 16},
        {EEK: "A", Energieträger: "Wärmepumpe", "frequency": 5},
        {EEK: "A", Energieträger: "Fernwärme", "frequency": 7},
        {EEK: "B", Energieträger: "Fernwärme", "frequency": 14},
        {EEK: "C", Energieträger: "Wärmepumpe", "frequency": 201},
        {EEK: "D", Energieträger: "Wärmepumpe", "frequency": 248},
        {EEK: "E", Energieträger: "Wärmepumpe", "frequency": 210},
        {EEK: "F", Energieträger: "Wärmepumpe", "frequency": 200},
        {EEK: "H", Energieträger: "Gas", "frequency": 28}
        ]
    };

 custom_scale = {
  "domain": ["Fernwärme", "Gas", "Gas dezentral", "BHKW", "Pellet",
        "Öl", "Wärmepumpe", "Elektro-Nachtspeicher", "Sonstiges"],
   "range": ["#0070C0", "#ED6011", "#FF0900", "#C00025", "#843C0C",
       "#000000", "#70AD47", "#6C7406", "#595959"]
};

const spec = {
    data: {name: 'values'},
        mark: {type: 'bar', size: 20, opacity: 1},
        encoding: {
            x: {field: 'EEK', type: 'nominal', sort: ["A+", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"], title: null, axis: {labelAngle: 0}},
            y: {field: 'frequency', type: 'quantitative', title: null},
            color: {field: 'Energieträger', type: 'nominal', scale: customScale},

        }
    },
}

return <VegaLite
    spec={spec}
    data={EEKData}
/>
```

Comment: My answer to your other question will also solve this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77390666/21427725

Answer (score 1):

Vega-Lite will use all the colours you provide in your scale. Do you need to set a custom domain and range? If you want the functionality you describe, you need to let VL calculate the colours for you automatically and then it will use only the ones in the data.

Another option is to provide the color in a field in your data if you need certain colours for specific categories.

Comment: How can I imagine this, to let VL calculate the colors? I'm sorry, I have no clue about that. Colud you give me an example or a keyword, so I can google for  it?

Comment: I can't use your code but it should be as simple as removing the scale in the line below. 


color: {field: 'Energieträger', type: 'nominal', scale: customScale},

Comment: Yes, okay, I know what you mean. But then I loose the consistency to have the same color for the same category everytime and in every plot. In addition, I need to use specific color values. I understand, I have to use your second solution an provide the color information in the data itself.

Comment: Yes, use the second solution in that case. Don't forget to mark as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by filtering the array of custom colors for every dataset according to the occurring categories and then using the sub array as color scale.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).