# Custom legend at the bottom in Vega-lite

Tags: legend, vega-lite

I had a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77366367/legend-colors-based-on-dynamic-lables) which [solution](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-aTgBdU4gTBtJCyCAAMzYbQQRlAdZogmtbTQrZocEEFwL9mrsjIW2MIAAnnANWhAUoEHJ6NVAnUKagZo6pzPSkd54uYMuyKvrWgLJ5juXHWQ2mwGDgmBOjCoQKWlAB3GiyZRsN8tkBsHBzCgW9ZEwew2z7C5nSUJADHQYCGFAzpnQvFpGzA1Bxwg-tzDMC9HSgHQoAYQQ1xUNQGAQSgEKQ0x3AAancAByAAPVBmIY9xVEwSjDCY5QmNLW44JAa9bxwT8j1QtUcCQKBJLQMQlBgYDZEIjDxzgNS2GUBTNEnbsQGwi4qiUTAJxwHVG102QdHsHpMEELZZBIwQYJYmg4NAUimD7ABhNhBEbcwmFIqAAGt6WOCtSKnLtMNAWTqwQODx1sjF0BgGgyBgYQcrAlo+0mDDQHMyzzBwNhPwK-95HQBcGAgOA2FILtorOEB0qsiTgIQQDCqcqASsrCydUq6rwN7ftUufcshU-C4nNHL96VfEBkDaSL9LKnUmBnFEb3C3awsiistOAmyj30ljDOM8wUDM0bzGtPrGzs9zPMMny+wAURYnB4vIniqO+wR7FBgKgsB0K5MipRr2dVAqz0eG2lMDYIAPTCJDENaEeUSHgvQa84EfJQAC8FrgG7UAsJRG17UCQrYbA2GbJQGybNRzAAUgACVQHnEkFgZ6TMugnPMZJtQIMYGGrHo5DFkAWPhfS7vQdIK2AqHDNU3TFbq8drVaXCKKo5R3AAXit5imiY+xtF0HU2lcMXSv0DCgcoyhLZtu2rAdpQnb0ELnfdytPbN4Hfet22mLjIOQBDnUSa01alCWrT6hcwRBArVpDrgJxTCXfT9bodgjcSjUkGbTLstyxuasQHBzLQOsdCa4OdFD2npJTtBz3p2T5Pb8u5ANqu-xN4aNZATpOiawbrWURf7DgABHBg7PQNg6zrZXB6iSgxEdJK6-MACaF6-rk97rYLAHh+h9PitMDYQKekAhKjKmi4HqVgljqAYqJ7JPXQC9Sq1YwYc0bMgL2PNlD8B5kwFBE53D80FokCO890ji0cjqH6K1HrlUga3N6sCjLwO5ugJBKC0E8wwVgoWq12qgA2ltUqECgERXsIXNgR0w6w2VudHSelQA0x7JBcwg5SE6igZQ+ywC0C5zcg4DyXkQAQ0CkTL4J17D4zQMjOAqN0awSxoYHGa1KZfmpqeemaMtJew-nfTmCDebINQeg8GSBfKCD+gDcwMBbxtAgAACm4rxJiKdBIAEo45eHcAAfi4ubPioNBLuHYkxB20VopzW8kgOKf4L4pT-F1YJjc8pYH4UVIahkdoVSqkzemdV1q3iai1OAbVpKcMaTwiA28NT9AOoI46IiWg0HJo-aIZ1tKXUMo+dW-9zBiTvApAhktUBqI+looxqBO6CG7ioNmSBPwdy7qY3h4U4JHJOQzZx5g0b5WVjIDot1VnoDMI45QPT7rQGzgpdq8pdHxVABXQ2M8o7fPNrHf2CcLBJ2PiAV2eEOqz2jj7P28ckTIpfprcOjpMWwpjjiu2Nh8Xh2Jq7dO0ks4rR2a5AuVZxkl2UGXCFk9K5K1-mUqpOUaktz6uPe51zj5PzWsfc8BTpKqTbFdUASBNGNOAYTaGBiKzEF7L+fSAihGQOHBAJKTz8lAA) was this. But now I want to change position of the legend to make it at the bottom like in the image. How it can be done?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMgGD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly hacked solution but try this.

Documentation:
https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/concat.html

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "123",
        "a": "Wed, 09 Aug 2023 06:00:00 GMT",
        "b": "Wed, 09 Aug 2023 17:00:23 GMT",
        "c": "A1",
        "d": "B1",
        "start_time": "Sat, 30 Dec 1899 06:00:00 GMT",
        "Date": "Wed, 09 Aug 2023"
      },
      {
        "id": "124",
        "a": "Wed, 09 Aug 2023 10:00:00 GMT",
        "b": "Wed, 09 Aug 2023 18:02:31 GMT",
        "c": "A2",
        "d": "B2",
        "start_time": "Sat, 30 Dec 1899 14:00:00 GMT",
        "Date": "Wed, 09 Aug 2023"
      },
      {
        "id": "125",
        "a": "Wed, 09 Aug 2023 19:01:07 GMT",
        "b": "Wed, 09 Aug 2023 22:01:17 GMT",
        "c": "A1",
        "d": "B2",
        "start_time": "Sat, 30 Dec 1899 22:00:00 GMT",
        "Date": "Wed, 09 Aug 2023"
      },
      {
        "id": "126",
        "a": "Wed, 07 Aug 2023 06:00:00 GMT",
        "b": "Wed, 07 Aug 2023 17:00:23 GMT",
        "c": "A4",
        "d": "B3",
        "start_time": "Sat, 30 Dec 1899 06:00:00 GMT",
        "Date": "Wed, 07 Aug 2023"
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "filter": {
        "field": "Date",
        "range": [
          {"year": 2023, "month": "Aug", "date": 7},
          {"year": 2023, "month": "Aug", "date": 10}
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "groupby": ["d"],
      "window": [{"op": "count", "field": "id", "as": "count_id"}],
      "sort": [{"field": "d"}]
    },
    {"calculate": "datum.count_id + 'x: ' + datum['d']", "as": "grouping"}
  ],
  "spacing": 5,
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "width": 300,
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "c",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "title": null,
          "axis": {"labelColor": "black"}
        }
      },
      "layer": [
        {
          "params": [
            {
              "name": "highlight",
              "select": {"type": "point", "on": "mouseover"}
            },
            {
              "name": "opicomp",
              "select": {"type": "point", "fields": ["d"]},
              "bind": "legend"
            }
          ],
          "mark": {"type": "bar", "stroke": "black"},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "a",
              "type": "temporal",
              "axis": {
                "labelExpr": "datum.label",
                "labelColor": "black",
                "grid": true,
                "gridDash": [5.5],
                "gridColor": "grey",
                "zindex": 1,
                "orient": "bottom",
                "format": "%H:%M:%S"
              },
              "title": "Time/Duration"
            },
            "x2": {"field": "b"},
            "color": {
              "condition": [
                {"test": "datum.d == 'B1'", "value": "red"},
                {"test": "datum.d == 'B2'", "value": "blue"},
                {"test": "datum.d == 'B3'", "value": "green"}
              ],
              "legend": null
            },
            "strokeWidth": {
              "condition": [{"param": "highlight", "empty": false, "value": 1}],
              "value": 0
            },
            "opacity": {
              "condition": [
                {
                  "test": {"field": "__selected__", "equal": "off"},
                  "value": 0.5
                },
                {"param": "opicomp", "value": 1}
              ],
              "value": 0.5
            },
            "tooltip": [
              {
                "field": "a",
                "title": "Start",
                "type": "temporal",
                "format": "%d-%b-%y %H:%M"
              },
              {
                "field": "b",
                "title": "End",
                "type": "temporal",
                "format": "%d-%b-%y %H:%M"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {"type": "point", "stroke": "transparent"},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Date",
              "type": "temporal",
              "title": null,
              "axis": {
                "labelColor": "black",
                "grid": true,
                "gridDash": [5.5],
                "zindex": 1,
                "orient": "top",
                "format": "%d-%b-%y",
                "labelExpr": "hours(datum['value']) == 0 ? datum['label'] : ''"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "width": 300,
      "params": [
        {"name": "highlight", "select": {"type": "point", "on": "mouseover"}}
      ],
      "mark": {
        "type": "rect",
        "cornerRadius": 3,
        "width": 15,
        "height": 15
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "grouping",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "axis": {
            "labelPadding": -7,
            "orient": "bottom",
            "title": null,
            "labelAngle": 0,
            "domain": false,
            "ticks": false,
            "labelLimit": 50
          },
          "sort": {"field": "d", "order": "ascending"}
        },
        "color": {
          "condition": [
            {"test": "datum.d == 'B1'", "value": "red"},
            {"test": "datum.d == 'B2'", "value": "blue"},
            {"test": "datum.d == 'B3'", "value": "green"}
          ],
          "value": "white"
        },
        "strokeWidth": {
          "condition": [{"param": "highlight", "empty": false, "value": 1}],
          "value": 0
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {"axis": {"titleColor": "black"}, "view": {"stroke": "transparent"}}
}
```

[image]

Comment: One question, here why when hovering over the bottom "legend" every time only  one of the entries or the last one is highlighted. Is there a way to highlight all components which have same color? [Link](https://t.ly/abeU0)